# ASP.NET Repeater Error: No default member found for type xx

Tags: asp.net, repeater

This is my repeater control in my .aspx page:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div><asp:HyperLink ID="hypItem" Text="sss" NavigateUrl="#" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And this is my codebehind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            rptEvents.DataSource = KTOEOS.Agenda.GetAgendaItems // returns a List(Of Agenda)
// Where Agenda is my object (created successfully)
            rptEvents.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub rptEvents_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptEvents.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
            Dim c As HyperLink = e.Item.FindControl("hypItem")
            c.Text = DateTime.Now & " > " & e.Item.DataItem("Date")
        End If
    End Sub
```

And I receive an error saying:

```
No default member found for type 'Agenda'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with below Modified code**

```
Dim c As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("hypItem"), HyperLink)
```

It should be like this `DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, YourClass).YourProperty`

Comment: thank you for the answer however, the error is highlighted here:  e.Item.DataItem("aDate")

Comment: It should be like this DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, YourClass).YourProperty

Comment: and DateTime.Now should be DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, your comment which I have upvoted have actually solved my problem. If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it..